# ubuntu 12.04.1 xserver problems

Tags: 12.04, ati, xserver

I have a problem with xserver on my laptop. Ubuntu 12.04.1 is installed. First, I can boot only in terminal mode. When I try to start xserver with command `startx` it fails.

`lspci | grep VGA` output: `01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Radeon Xpress 1250`

xorg.0.log:

```
[  3947.214] 
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[  3947.223] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  3947.226] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-26-generic i686 Ubuntu
[  3947.228] Current Operating System: Linux argentum 3.2.0-35-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 17:45:18 UTC 2012 i686
[  3947.228] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic root=UUID=4ef621ed-26dd-46fd-80bc-b04ad5f18990 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[  3947.232] Build Date: 29 August 2012  12:10:05AM
[  3947.235] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  3947.237] Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
[  3947.241]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  3947.241] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  3947.251] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan 12 22:16:17 2013
[  3947.253] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  3947.253] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  3947.253] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  3947.253] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  3947.253] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""
[  3947.254] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  3947.254] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  3947.254] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  3947.254] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  3947.254]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  3947.254] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins
[  3947.254] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  3947.254] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  3947.254] (II) Loader magic: 0x5475a0
[  3947.254] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  3947.254]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  3947.254]    X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
[  3947.254]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[  3947.254]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[  3947.255] (--) PCI:*(0:1:5:0) 1002:7942:144d:c034 rev 0, Mem @ 0xd0000000/134217728, 0xd8000000/65536, I/O @ 0x00009000/256
[  3947.255] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[  3947.255] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[  3947.256] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[  3947.256] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  3947.256]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  3947.256]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  3947.256]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  3947.256] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  3947.256] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  3947.256] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[  3947.256] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[  3947.256] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[  3947.256] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  3947.256] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[  3947.256] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[  3947.256] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[  3947.256] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  3947.256]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  3947.256]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  3947.256]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  3947.256] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  3947.256] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  3947.257] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  3947.257] (II) Module glx: vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc."
[  3947.257]    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
[  3947.257] (II) Loading extension GLX
[  3947.257] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[  3947.258] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[  3947.258] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  3947.258]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
[  3947.258]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  3947.258]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  3947.258] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[  3947.258] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[  3947.258] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[  3947.258] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  3947.258]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  3947.258]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  3947.258] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[  3947.258] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  3947.258] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[  3947.259] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  3947.259]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[  3947.259]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  3947.259] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[  3947.259] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[  3947.259] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[  3947.259] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[  3947.259] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[  3947.259] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  3947.259] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[  3947.259] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[  3947.283] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - ATI Technologies Inc."
[  3947.283]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 8.95.3
[  3947.283]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  3947.284] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[  3947.284] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[  3947.284] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
[  3947.284] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - ATI Technologies Inc."
[  3947.284]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 8.95.3
[  3947.284] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[  3947.285] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[  3947.285] (II) UnloadModule: "ati"
[  3947.285] (II) Unloading ati
[  3947.285] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
[  3947.285] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  3947.285] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[  3947.285] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  3947.285] (II) Unloading vesa
[  3947.285] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[  3947.285] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  3947.286] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[  3947.286] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  3947.286] (II) Unloading fbdev
[  3947.286] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[  3947.286] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[  3947.286] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[  3947.286] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[  3947.286] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[  3947.286] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  3947.286] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[  3947.286] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[  3947.286] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - ATI Technologies Inc."
[  3947.286]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 8.95.3
[  3947.286]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  3947.286] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[  3947.287] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[  3947.287] (II) UnloadModule: "ati"
[  3947.287] (II) Unloading ati
[  3947.287] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
[  3947.287] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  3947.287] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[  3947.287] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  3947.287] (II) Unloading vesa
[  3947.287] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[  3947.287] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  3947.288] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[  3947.288] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  3947.288] (II) Unloading fbdev
[  3947.288] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[  3947.288] (II) ATI Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:8.95.3
[  3947.288] (II) ATI Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: 8.951                                
[  3947.288] (II) ATI Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: Mar  8 2012 23:06:36
[  3947.288] (--) using VT number 7

[  3947.293] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[  3947.293] (EE) Unable to initialize PCS database
[  3947.293] (EE)   Missing PCS defaults file /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
[  3947.293] (EE) No devices detected.
[  3947.293] 
Fatal server error:
[  3947.293] no screens found
[  3947.293] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  3947.293] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  3947.293]
```

Seems, that I have a problem with AMD/ATI drivers. Is it possible to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **uninstall fglrx drivers** *(the ATI Radeon Xpress 1250 card isn't supported by current version of fglrx)*.

`sudo apt-get purge fgrlx`
or
`sudo apt-get purge fglrx-updates` (the after-release updates)

After, ensure that `radeon` driver is installed. OSS packages are: `xserver-xorg-video-radeon`, `libdrm-radeon1`.